# Подскажите как сделать адекватное поведение анимации в Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animate

Анимация работает так:  элемент в виде круга вращается просто по своей оси. Не могу эту же анимацию сделать в Mozilla Firefox.
Вот код:

```css
#saw{
  animation: saw 0.3s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation: saw 0.4s infinite linear;
  -moz-transform-origin: 74% 52%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
@keyframes saw {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes saw {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="saw"></div>
```

Так работает и в мозиле, но все равно крутиться не на месте .

Comment: Добавьте разметку и остальные стили с которыми работаете. непонятно к чему это всё применяется.......... и  что значит `но все равно крутиться не на месте .` ?

Comment: У вас для хрома написано крутить вокруг центра `transform-origin: 50% 50%;`...... для firefox написано крутить вокруг точки со смещением `-moz-transform-origin: 74% 52%;`....... для оперы так вообще относительно нижнего левого угла `0% 100%;` .......... то есть, полагаю, дело в невнимательности и незнании css?

Comment: Стилей нету, #saw это часть svg  картинки, я не смогу так разметку скинуть, для оперы нету префикса, опера использует стили для хрома, это стиль для IE, просто попробуйте саму анимацию у себя и не надо намикать на незнание CSS, просто присвойте ее простому кргугу

Comment: Лучше каким-то образом визуально изобразите что происходит..... т.к. из озвученных вами слов непонятно в чем конкретно проблема..... если как я сказал не в тех координатах - то проблема решена... если не в этом - тогда никто никогда не поймет и не сможет вам помочь

Comment: как здесь редактировать код ?!)

Comment: только что проверял на простом div border-radius:50%(что есть круг), работает адекватно при transform-orign: 50% 50% во всех браузерах,  а вот эти же стили заданные svg картинке в мозиле работает не так как надо

Comment: Вы немного некорректно отредактировали код....... во-первых там не видно круга, о котором вы говорите. во-вторых непонятно причем тут `svg`. В-третьих если он как-то причем - то надо написать каким образом и добавить это самое `svg` а не что-то еще. В-четвертых: что будет при `-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/owu77c6q/